# Making buttons in recyclerview and cardview clickable

Tags: java, android-studio, button, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've added buttons into a a cardview and recyclerview. I'm struggling to make the buttons clickable. Every time I click the buttons it's actually registering the recyclerview as being clicked.

**Activity containing cardview and recyclerview**

```
package com.khumomashapa.notes.activities;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.adapter.RecyclerAdapter;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.arraylists.Messages;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Widget
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //Firebase
    private DatabaseReference mref;

    // Variable
    private ArrayList<Messages> messagesList;

    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    Button PurchaseBtn;
    Button DownloadBtn;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.products_view);

        PurchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PurchaseBtn);
        DownloadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DownloadBtn);


        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        PurchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext()
        ,recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
                Drawable mDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),PreviewActivity.class);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[]bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                intent.putExtra("image", bytes);
                startActivity(intent);
                Messages messages = messagesList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(StoreActivity.this, "You have selected: "+ messages.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }

                    @Override
                    public void onButtonClicks(View view, int position) {

                    }
                })
        );




        // Firebase

        mref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        // Arraylist

        messagesList = new ArrayList<Messages>();

        // Clear arraylist

        ClearAll();

        // Get data Method

        GetDataFromFirebase();
    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase(){
        Query query = mref.child("Wallpapers");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ClearAll();


                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Messages messages = new Messages();

                    messages.setImage(snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                    messages.setTitle(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());

                    messagesList.add(messages);


                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), messagesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });





    }

    private void ClearAll(){
        if(messagesList != null){
            messagesList.clear();

            if (recyclerAdapter !=null){
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }

        messagesList = new ArrayList<Messages>();
    }

}
```

**Recycler Adapter**

```
package com.khumomashapa.notes.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.StoreActivity;
import com.khumomashapa.notes.arraylists.Messages;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String Tag = "RecyclerView";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Messages> messagesList;

    Button PurchaseBtn;
    Button DownloadBtn;

    View imageView;


    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Messages> messagesArrayList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messagesList = messagesArrayList;

        View imageView;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false);





        return new ViewHolder(view);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Textview
        holder.textView.setText(messagesList.get(position).getTitle());

        holder.PurchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });



        // Imageview: Glide library

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(messagesList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return messagesList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Widgets;

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        Button PurchaseBtn;
        Button DownloadBtn;

        View v;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);

             PurchaseBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PurchaseBtn);
             DownloadBtn =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.DownloadBtn);

            View v;

        }
    }
}
```

**Recycler Touch Listener**

```
package com.khumomashapa.notes.activities

import android.content.Context
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener


class RecyclerTouchListener(
    context: Context?,
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    private val clickListener: ClickListener?
) :
    OnItemTouchListener {
    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(recyclerView: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(recyclerView: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}
    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
    interface ClickListener {
        fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int)
        fun onLongClick(view: View?, position: Int)
        fun onButtonClicks(view: View?, position: Int)
    }

    init {
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                val child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Cardview layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Imagelayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/ImageView"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Imagelayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/biorhyme_extralight"
                android:id="@+id/Title"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/PurchaseBtn"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:onClick="purchase"
                android:text="@string/purchase"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Title"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                android:focusable="true" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/DownloadBtn"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/PurchaseBtn"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
                android:text="@string/download"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Recyclerview layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.StoreActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/products_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout >
```

Another issue I know I'll encounter is the null reference exception.
How do I reference the buttons from the cardview layout when the content view is set to be shown from the other one.

[image]